# Gathering data using sqlalchemy from database and making it available using simplified namedtuple object in an iterable class

Tags: python, python-3.x, database, sqlalchemy

I wrote the below code today:

```
class Hosts(object):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Hosts, self).__init__()
        engine, connection = _core.get_engine()
        self._engine = engine
        self._connection = connection
        self._lan_table = self.get_table()


    def _get_selected_field_value(self, table, fields, col_value=None, limit=1):
            """Performs select Operation and gets the value of field.

            Arguments:
                table (sqlalchemy.Table) : table to select data from.
                fields (list) : fields whose value to retrieve.
                col_value (dict) : where column of table has value.
            """
            col_value = col_value or {}
            stmt = db.select(fields).where(
                and_(*[
                    getattr(
                        table.columns,
                         column
                         ) == value for column, value in col_value.items()
                    ])
                ).order_by(db.desc(table.columns.id)).limit(limit)
            _log.debug(stmt)
            ResultProxy = self._connection.execute(stmt)
            ResultSet = ResultProxy.fetchall()
            for item in ResultSet:
                yield item

    def _get_user_and_hostname(self):
        """Gets the hostname of the machine from host table.
        """
        _log.debug("Using table %s", self._lan_table)
        column_value = {"ip_address": self._ip}
        return next(self._get_selected_field_value(
            self._lan_table, 
            [self._lan_table.columns.name, self._lan_table.columns.user], 
            col_value=column_value
            ),
        None
        )


    def _get_all(self):
        limit = self._engine.scalar(self._lan_table.count())
        columns = Host.metadata.tables['host'].columns.keys()
        columns.pop(columns.index("mac_address"))
        _host = namedtuple("Host", columns)
        select_fields = [getattr(self._lan_table.columns, column) for column in columns]
        self._rows = []
        for rows in self._get_selected_field_value(
                self._lan_table,
                select_fields,
                limit=limit
                ):
            self._rows.append(_host(*rows))
        return self._rows

    def __iter__(self):
        table_data = self._get_all()
        return iter(table_data)
```

Here is the `self._lan_table`

```
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field       | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id          | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name        | varchar(250) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| user        | varchar(20)  | NO   |     | root    |                |
| ip_address  | varchar(18)  | NO   | UNI | NULL    |                |
| mac_address | varchar(250) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| is_linux    | tinyint(1)   | NO   |     | 1       |                |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

**my question** is for the intuitive and pythonic approach and correctness of sqlalchemy !

I know when I `fetchall` it pulls all data at once, however my table has just 12 rows.

As is understood the appraoch  in code is letting me do this:

```
hosts = Hosts()
for item in hosts:
    print(item)
```

**Take the Challenge !**

Comment: What Problem are you trying to solve with this code?

Comment: Host column fields and their values are available when class object is  iterated rather than sqlalchemy object.

Comment: your title just seems really lengthy, but I think I get it. if you can make the title shorter you should.